# Inequality optimization, KKT condition.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

So we have the problem: maximize $x^2+y^2$ subject to $x^2-y \leq3$ and $y\leq 1$.
And I sorted out the KKT conditions for the problem (is here where the problem is?):

$2x=\lambda _12x$,

$2y=\lambda_2-\lambda_1$,

$\lambda_1\geq0$ with $\lambda_1=0$ if $x^2-y<3$,

$\lambda_2\geq0$ with $\lambda_2=0$ if $y<1$.

So I check the KKT condition one by one: both constraints are active, only one is active, none is active, etc.

But my problem comes as follows: suppose the first constraint is active and the second inactive. So we have $y<1$, $\lambda_2=0$, $2y=-\lambda_1$.

I don't know what to proceed after that, I mean, say if $x=0$, then $\lambda_1$ can take any value. So what does it mean when $\lambda$ is supposed to be a constant?

Comment: Then, $x^2-y=3$. Your slackness condition is $\lambda_1 \ge 0, x^2-y\le 3, \lambda_1(x^2-y-3)=0$

Comment: Oh, that's right, thanks! But if I consider both constraint inactive, I get $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ with $y=0$ and $x^2<3$, so does it mean the entire set $(x,0):x^2<3$ satisfies KKT? In other words, KKT condition can in fact give you an infinite set of candidates?

Comment: Depends on problem. It can be unbounded as well...

Comment: In your case if you simplify the first condition then $\lambda_1=1$ (assuming $x\neq 0$). Then you have two cases $\lambda_2=0$ ($y=-1/2,x^2=7/2$) and $\lambda_2=3$ ($y=1,x^2=4$)